# Characterization of surface blow up

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, birational-geometry

Let $X$ be an connected surface which set-theoretically is the union of $\mathbb{P}^2-pt$ and $\mathbb{P}^1$. Suppose there is a birational morphism $\pi:X\to\mathbb{P}^2$ such that all of $\mathbb{P}^1$ above is mapped to the point. Does this imply that $X$ is the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at that point?

If we know in addition that $X$ is smooth, then it is classical that the existence of $\pi$ implies $X$ is the blow-up. But is it possible for some singular surface $X$ to have the above property?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This can happen. For example, blow up the point $p$ and blow up a point in the exceptional divisor. Then the first exceptional divisor is a -2 curve which can be blown down to get a singular point and then you have a $\mathbb{P}^1$ the second exceptional divisor maps to a point.

Comment: To add to Mohan's comment: if this sounds like the beginning of an interesting story to you, the key term is "Hirzebruch Surface."